# rails server started but cannot connect to localhost on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have rails 4 app. this morning I open up my computer and start rails server. rails server started perfectly as ever but when in browser localhost:3000 not connecting to my app.

I've tried apt-get update my ubuntu.
I've tried rails server with other port number.

Comment: What do you see in your log when you hit `localhost:3000`?

Comment: I see nothing bro, when I hit localhost:3000 browser reload once and nothing happened

Comment: In my terminal ..
=> Booting Thin \n
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3001 \n
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options \n
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server \n
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:3001, CTRL+C to stop

Comment: So, its listening on port 3001, what do you see when you hit: `localhost:3001`?

Comment: yes .. i've tried with the other port number like 3001. it does the same. nothing happened. not showing any error message. browser just reload and stay blank. i'm serious.

Comment: What does the actual entry in the development.log file say (there should be an entry for every request made to the app server)

Comment: Maybe try `127.0.0.1:3000/`

Comment: What u c when u type netstat -lnp?